# Nuxt.js with Express on Heroku - SPA and logging not working

Tags: express, heroku, nuxt.js

May I ask for the help of the community? My issue:

I have successfully deployed my Nuxt.js site to heroku but I am facing two things

1. My app does not behave like a SPA. Moving from one menu to another loads all the files all the times. (This works perfectly fine on localhost).
2. `heroku logs` gives me nothing no matter what

Have you ever seen something like this? *(Those who run Nuxt.js with Express on Heroku)*

Could you please give me some hints if you are more familiar with heroku, what can I do to at least to have a clue what is wrong with the setup?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section on the nuxt.js guide for deploying to Heroku. Apparently, you have to set the nuxt.config.js file to include the following

```
mode: 'spa'
```

They have other modes as well. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands